# Graphviz does not show graph/pdf image in Spyder

Tags: python

I'm trying to show BFS and UCS graphs using Graphviz with Spyder. My output is correct, however, no graph/pdf is shown when run. A snippet of my code related to Graphviz is below:

```
import graphviz
from graph import graph
from graph import graph_weights
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/location/of/files/'
f = graphviz.Digraph('G', filename='bfs.gv')
for i in Path:  # For each node in Path
    f.node(i)   # Add node to graphviz object
# For each node in Path except the last one
for i in range(len(Path)-1):
    # Add edge between the node and the next node
    f.edge(Path[i], Path[i+1])
f.view()    # View the graphviz object
print('Path from {} to {} is: {}'.format(
    start, end, Path))  # Print message
```

I've tried both `f.view()` and `f.render()` and nothing is shown. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Thank you.